# Meus ícones não estão sendo add ao .JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, image, icons, jlabel

Boa tarde, estou com um problema na hora de compilar minha aplicação.

Estou usando Apache NetBeans 11.0
Java 8

Estou tendo problemas na hora de setar uma imagem em um JLabel.

Me retorna
Expection in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon:217)
at br.house.main.mainBotPainel.initComponents(mainBotPainel.java:63)
...

Todas as imagens foram add na pasta assets. Segue em anexo 2 prints.

Como nada funcionava, peguei o .JAR e mandei abrir com winRAR e dentro dele não constava a pasta assets, ou seja, ela n foi encapsulada junto com o JAR pelo Netbeans. O q estou fazendo de errado?

[image: As imagens e ícones foram add na pasta assets]

[image: A linha de código aonde ocorre o erro]

Answer (score 1):

Consegui a ajuda no  GUJ para a solução do problema e venho aqui compartilhar caso futuramente alguém esteja passando pelo mesmo problema.

Fui solicitado por um usuario do GUJ a postar a árvore expandida da aba 'Files' do meu projeto no NetBeans.

[image: árvore expandida da aba Files]

Recebi a seguinte solução apos o print acima.

"Legal, seu problema não é o NetBeans muito menos o Java mas sim sua estrutura de pastas.
Este é um projeto Maven, então você tem que seguir uma certa estrutura de pastas (pra não ficar alterando pom.xml).

Seus fontes Java já estão no lugar certo, que é a seguinte pasta:

src\main\java
Já suas imagens e outros resources precisam estar na seguinte pasta:

src\main\resources
Então cria essa pasta e move a pasta assets pra dentro dela que vai funcionar."

E foi batata. Problema resolvido!